# Migrating development database onto Heroku with Django

Tags: python, django, heroku, migration

I am having trouble migrating my development database onto Heroku. This is for a personal project written in Django.

**settings.py**

```
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config()
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
```

I've migrated the database locally and pushed the migration onto Heroku already. Then, I ran the `heroku run python manage.py migrate` command to migrate the database on Heroku.

I had accidentally ran `makemigrations` on Heroku, but have restarted my dynos since.

Currently, my database on Heroku is not populated at all.

Comment: What are you expecting to populate your db? Migrations will create the tables, but it's up to you to create the data.

Comment: Thank you! Sounds like I should just create a script that runs on bootup to populate the prod database with some initial data